# Merging git branch into another branch with outstanding pull requests

Tags: git, version-control, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

To start I apologise if this is a duplicate, I had a look and couldn't find anything that matched.

My team and I have been having some issues recently with Git (using SourceTree GUI) and I was hoping someone could help. We have a system where we take our hotfix branches from the master branch and merge them into a release candidate (RC) branch once the request has been fixed.

Suppose Bob and John both have hotfixes so they each take a branch from master and work separately. When Bob has finished his work, he pulls the RC branch and merges his change in. This is generally fine.

The issue we have is that occasionally, John will then merge his work into the RC branch without resolving the outstanding pull request caused by Bob's commit. SourceTree will then pop up a message saying John needs to pull the RC branch but this can cause merge conflicts and can result (and has resulted) in the work Bob did in being completely erased, but then it can't be merged in again as it's already in the branch history.

I know the obvious answer is just make sure you do the pull request before merging, but in the event John does the merge without resolving the pull request, is there a way we can guarantee no work is lost?

I have looked into rebasing which seems to work, but i'm wary about using this too much as the RC branch is public and edited by everyone in the team.

Answer (score 0):

Since RC branch is used by all developers, you’d better not rebase this branch.
Except pull request, there has other options you can refer:

1.John merge into `RC` branch directly, if it need to use Bob’s version later, you can reset or reapply Bob’s version by cherry-pick.

```
# In John’s local repo
git checkout RC
git pull origin RC
git diff  RC..hotfix  #to find the files difference between the branches
git merge hotfix
# modify and solve conflict files
git add .
git commit
```

If there need to keep the version of Bob’s later, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~` and re-merge John's hotfix into RC and solve the conflicts with the other side version. Or you can use `git cherry-pick <commit id Bob merged into RC>` to re-apply Bpb’s version.

2.If you have QA team to test `RC` branch when there have changes to be merged into `RC`, both John and Bob can push there local hotfix (`hotfix_Bob`, `hotfix_John`) branches to remote. Then QA team test and merge hotfix branches into `RC`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if either of these will work though. 1) Our RC branch is a culmination of all hotfixes and new feautres throughout a month so it has to have all work, so this is basically the same as what we do at the moment. 2) We do have a QA team that tests our fixes but they do this on the RC branch as they don't have the technical skills to merge the branches themselves (we are quite a small company)

Comment: You can test and practice with a demo git repo for the first option.